# Java: PatternSyntaxException thrown with regex .*-\\d+{.*}\\d+-.*

Tags: java, regex, string, match, patternsyntaxexception

I am trying to make a regex to determine if a String contains a `-`, some amount of digits, a `{`, nothing/some sequence of characters, a `}`, some amount of digits, and a final `-`. For example:

```
gibberish-345{randomtext}938475-moregibberish

^&*^%^asdf-9897689{symbols$%&*}456-h6

-456{}456-
```

I have tried using `String.matches("*-\\d+{.*}\\d+-.*")` and `String.matches("*-[\\d]+{.*}[\\d]+-.*")`, but in each case I get a `PatternSyntaxException` (both of them are below):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 5
.*-\d+{.*}\d+-.*
 ^
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.matches(Unknown Source)
at conv.Congine.qual(Congine.java:17)
at conv.Congine.convert(Congine.java:5)
at conv.Main.main(Main.java:6)

~

Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 7
.*-[\d]+{.*}[\d]+-.*
   ^
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.matches(Unknown Source)
at conv.Congine.qual(Congine.java:17)
at conv.Congine.convert(Congine.java:5)
at conv.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

Am I using a regex symbol that I don't know I'm using? I've checked, but I don't think that -, {, or } qualifies as a regex symbol...

Comment: Have you tried just `\\d+`, without the brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern should be

```
.*-\\d+\\{.*\\}\\d+-.*
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I can answer my own question... apparently `{` and `}` *are* special characters in regex, you have to escape them with `\\`. Oh well.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed that... but yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.matches("*-\\d+\\{.*}\\d+-.*");
```

It's mainly because of the `{` character next to the `+` symbol. We all know, in regex, `+` repeats the previous token one or more times where as the repetition quantifier `{start,end}` repeats the previous token according to the range given inside the `{}` curly braces. So the regex engine considers the `{` as the start of the repetition quantifier and `+` before the `{` causes this to fail. We can't specify `o+{2}` but we do `(o+){2}`. And also you don't need to escape the closing curly bracket.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern will be:

```
^.*[-]\\d+\\{.*\\}\\d+[-].*$
```

Thanks,